# MYSQL query optimisation using Distinct

Tags: mysql

I want to find the number of users who accessed the app via notification per day. The query I wrote was very slow.

```
SELECT DATE(user_statistics.timestamp) date, COUNT(*) count FROM post
INNER JOIN user_statistics ON user_statistics.post_id = post.id
AND user_statistics.access_type = 'notification' AND post.type = 'given_type'
GROUP BY DATE(user_statistics.timestamp)
```

I rewrote it to make it faster by using `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(user_statistics.timestamp), count(DISTINCT user_statistics.post_id) 
FROM user_statistics INNER JOIN post on post.id = user_statistics.post_id
WHERE post.type = 'given_type' AND access_type = 'notification'
```

New query is not working. It says

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list
>   contains nonaggregated column 'user_statistics.timestamp'; this
>   is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add group by clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(user_statistics.timestamp), count(DISTINCT user_statistics.post_id) 
FROM user_statistics INNER JOIN post on post.id = user_statistics.post_id
WHERE post.type = 'given_type' AND access_type = 'notification'
group by date(user_statistics.timestamp)
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` would seem to be superfluous given the rest of the query.

Comment: I removed group by and added distinct to make the query run faster. Can this be made faster by any other means?

Comment: how much time it takes to execute now